# Qual è il significato di "apprestare l'opra bella" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> I cinque, creduti attori principali del movimento, erravano, ma, colla fede dei martiri, avevano giurato, sorpresi, di patire qualsiasi tortura, non mai rivelando i nomi dei compagni. Né più tardi, il labbro loro si schiuse a consumare una viltà. Trascorso più che un mese dagli attacchi rivoltosi, i cinque profughi da San Mauro furono condotti, e **l'opra bella apprestavano** il prete Zito e Rosaria Calascibetta, a Pettineo da Mauro Giallombardo, cugino dei Botta. 
>   Ospitati in una casa di Giovanni Sirena, si concertavano i mezzi meno scabrosi per espatriare, recandosi in Malta; poiché funeste addippiù giungevano le notizie degli arrestati, di Giuseppe Maggio, di 
>   Pasquale e Andrea Maggio fu Antonino, di Giuseppe Re, spontaneamente presentatosi, di Salvatore Bevilacqua, di Vincenzo Sapienza, di Antonino Spinuzza, di Salvatore Maranto del contadino Santi Cefalù. I quali soffrivano troppo, né pareva avessero da sperare la liberazione o la mitigazione delle pene.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "apprestare l'opra bella" in questo passaggio? Nei dizionari che ho consultato ho visto che "opra" è lo stesso di "opera", quindi ho cercato i vocaboli "apprestare" e "opera", ma non riesco a capire il senso della frase che appare nel testo. Significa che il prete Zito e Rosaria Calascibetta hanno fatto una buona opera, cioè hanno aiutato alla causa?

Comment: Occorrerebbe avere un po’ piú di contesto. Chi sono «i cinque»? Di che «movimento» si parla? Ad ogni modo, come si sarà accorta, il testo è improntato a un linguaggio tradizionalmente letterario nel lessico e nella sintassi. A quanto mi consta, non esiste un’espressione idiomatica «bell’opera» (e varianti) né nella lingua moderna né in quella tradizionale. Pertanto, credo che la locuzione vada intesa alla lettera: «Preparavano la bella opera, attività, ecc.». In assenza di ulteriore contesto, quel «bella» potrebbe anche essere inteso in senso ironico.

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu: Il brano fa riferimento ai movimenti rivoluzionari contro i Borboni avvenutosi a Cefalù nel 1856 e ha un linguaggio volutamente ottocentesco. «I cinque» sono Salvatore Spinuzza, Nicolò Botta, Carlo Botta, Andrea Maggio e Alessandro Guarnera.

Comment: Più che specificamente ottocentesco è addirittura iperletterario, giacché vi si trovano, in una prosa cronachistica, addirittura inversioni e forme tipiche del linguaggio poetico (un esempio che comprende tutto, «l’opra bella apprestavano»). Non so perché l’autore, un contemporaneo, abbia fatto questa scelta stilistica. Comunque sia, 1) non è un idiomatismo; 2) _opra_ si riferisce a un’azione che si deve desumere dal contesto (un’insurrezione?) e _bella_ implica o un giudizio positivo o negativo, se si tratta di un uso ironico.

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu: Infatti (adesso me n'accorgo) si tratta di parte di un documento storico (*Il moto politico di Cefalù nel 1856*, Cefalù, Tipografia Salv. Gussio, 1907) scritto da Francesco Guardione.